# Flutter height not adjusting as expected

Tags: flutter, dart

```
child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.white,
                spreadRadius: 1,
                blurRadius: 0.6,
                offset: Offset(1, 1))
          ]),
```

In this Flutter app, I am trying to adjust the height by replacing any numbers and even I change and change it is not working as expected. Is there somthing fix the height so I could not adjust the size?

Comment: It all depends on what its parent  is. If it were to be in a `Center` for example it would probably work correctly

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints says: "When someone learning Flutter asks you why some widget with width: 100 isn’t 100 pixels wide, the default answer is to tell them to put that widget inside of a Center, right?

Don’t do that." @Ivo

Comment: @pskink yeah I'm not telling him that he should use a Center, just that the size would probably be correct then.

Comment: How to check their parent elements in Flutter?